# Terminal / Editor themes for colourblindness?

Tags: vim, terminal, colors

I "suffer" (not really) from a difficult-to-diagnose form of colourblindness. It generally corresponds with red-green colourblindness, but there are some quirks. There's a definite cognitive element to whatever's going on, and for kicks I can see some "secret colours" that other people can't.

Anyway - it can be very hard to read text in different colours, or to differentiate between colours.

I adore Ethan Schoonover's popular [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) theme, but I find it very hard to pick apart some of the colours in the Light theme. The dark theme is easier, but I don't want to be looking at a dark theme all day!

I could spend forever tweaking the colours, but I'm not very good at thinking about stuff like this, and surely someone else has put some thought into this. Does anyone know of themes for terminal applications and so on (mainly, something I can just shove into MacVim) designed with degrees of colourblindness in mind?

I found TextMate's Blackboard theme very clear, but I've gone back to Vim and, again, I want something nice and light.

Comment: Forever tweaking? There are only 16 colors!

Comment: Fair point. But you know, these themes are designed by people who a) are smart and b) know what they're doing. I am a maximum of one of those things. I love the consistency and balance of Solarized, and I feel dirty breaking it by picking some arbitrary colour and sticking it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't think anyone really understands what you are experiencing more than yourself, here are 428 different colorschemes for you to choose from with code samples from [VimColorSchemeTest](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/).

- [C](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-c.html)
- [HTML](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-html.html)
- [Java](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-java.html)
- [Perl](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-pl.html)
- [LaTeX](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-tex.html)

It takes a while to load up each page. You can grab the `.vim` by clicking on their respective names.